# Django handle new ManyToManyField items with get_or_create()

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a model with a ManyToManyField and in my view I want to be able to add new options to the generated selectbox

How can I handle those new items with get_or_create function?

I want to check for form validity before saving it, but it will never be valid because I have to create all the new ManyToMany items.

In the meantime, I don't want to add new items if the form is not valid...

So I'm stuck with this not-working-code:

```
def add_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
        for tag in model_instance.tags.all():
            t, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(author=request.user, title=tag.title)
            model_instance.tags.add(t)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        form = EntryForm()
    return render_to_response(
        'add_entry.html',
        {'form' : form },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

EDIT:

my code is now

```
def add_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = EntryForm()
    return render_to_response(
            'add_entry.html',
            {'form' : form },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )
```

and i can save existing tags, but i can't dinamically add new ones...

Comment: > "I want to check for form validity before saving it, but it will never be valid because I have to create all the new ManyToMany items."

What's the `ValidationError` you get here?

Comment: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>tags<ul class="errorlist"><li>&quot;asdasd&quot; is no
t a valid value for a primary key.</li></ul></li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using some sort of `JS` to add the `tags` dynamically. I suggest you to go further and create an API endpoint where you can actually save the created tags so they can became a valid options of the selectbox.